# Building an ensemble of Random Forest models with VotingClassifier()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to build an ensemble of some models using VotingClassifier() from Sklearn to see if it works better than the individual models. I'm trying it in 2 different ways.

1. I'm trying to do it with individual Random Forest, Gradient Boosting, and XGBoost models.
2. I'm trying to build it using an ensemble of many Random Forest models (using different parameters for n_estimators and max_depth.

In the first condition, I'm doing this

```
estimator = []
estimator.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                       criterion='gini', max_depth=8, max_features='auto',
                       max_leaf_nodes=None, max_samples=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=900,
                       n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True, random_state=66, verbose=0,
                       warm_start=True)))
estimator.append(('GB', GradientBoostingClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, criterion='friedman_mse', init=None,
                           learning_rate=0.03, loss='deviance', max_depth=5,
                           max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                           min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                           min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                           min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=1000,
                           n_iter_no_change=None, presort='deprecated',
                           random_state=66, subsample=1.0, tol=0.0001,
                           validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=0,
                           warm_start=False)))
estimator.append(('XGB', xgb.XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
              learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=9,
              min_child_weight=1, n_estimators=1000, n_jobs=1,
              nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
              silent=None, subsample=1, verbosity=1)))
```

And when I do

```
ensemble_model_churn = VotingClassifier(estimators = estimator, voting ='soft')
```

and display ensemble_model_churn, I get everything in the output.

But under the second condition, I'm doing this

```
estimator = []
estimator.append(('RF_1',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500,max_depth=5,warm_start=True)))
estimator.append(('RF_2',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500,max_depth=6,warm_start=True)))
estimator.append(('RF_3',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500,max_depth=7,warm_start=True)))
estimator.append(('RF_4',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=500,max_depth=8,warm_start=True)))
```

And so on. I have 30 different models like that.

But this time, when I do

```
ensemble_model_churn = VotingClassifier(estimators = estimator, voting ='soft')
```

and display it, I get only the first one, and not the other ones.

```
print(ensemble_model_churn)
>>>VotingClassifier(estimators=[('RF_1',
                              RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True,
                                                     ccp_alpha=0.0,
                                                     class_weight=None,
                                                     criterion='gini',
                                                     max_depth=5,
                                                     max_features='auto',
                                                     max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                                     max_samples=None,
                                                     min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                                     min_impurity_split=None,
                                                     min_samples_leaf=1,
                                                     min_samples_split=2,
                                                     min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                                     n_estimators=500,
                                                     n_jobs=None,
                                                     oob_score=...
                                                     criterion='gini',
                                                     max_depth=5,
                                                     max_features='auto',
                                                     max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                                     max_samples=None,
                                                     min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                                     min_impurity_split=None,
                                                     min_samples_leaf=1,
                                                     min_samples_split=2,
                                                     min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                                     n_estimators=500,
                                                     n_jobs=None,
                                                     oob_score=False,
                                                     random_state=None,
                                                     verbose=0,
                                                     warm_start=True))],
                 flatten_transform=True, n_jobs=None, voting='soft',
                 weights=None)
```

Why is this happening? Is it not possible to run an ensemble of the same model?

Comment: In the second `estimator` case, are you building from *only* random forest classifiers? A `VotingClassifier` instance clones the original estimators, if two classifiers are of the same type then it could be dropping them assuming they are duplicates.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes Is there an alternative to VotingClassifier() that handles this type of ensemble?

Comment: Usually you wouldn't want to. In your hyperparameters: the `max_depth` are initialized as 5, 6, 7, 8. Depth-5 decision trees are a strict subset of depth-6, which are a strict subset of depth-7 trees, which are a strict subset of depth-8 decision trees.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I'm just trying to find if such an ensemble works better than using GridSearchCV on a bunch of estimators. Just not able to do it with VotingClassifier().

Comment: If you want to "roll your own" voting classifier you can column-append the `y_pred` of each RF, giving you a Nx30 matrix. The mode of each row would then be a hard vote.

Comment: cross-posted at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/93137/55122

Comment: @BenReiniger since this is actually a coding issue, it was rightfully posted here instead of DSSE; I do flag similar cases, too, but only on *one* of the sites, not to both of them. Have done so in DSSE, so I kindly suggest you remove your last comment here/

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes That sounds like a good workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing more than one of the estimators, it's just a little hard to tell.  Notice the ellipses (`...`) after the first `oob_score` parameter, and that after those some of the hyperparameters are repeated. Python just doesn't want to print such a giant wall of text, and has trimmed out most of the middle.  You can check that `len(ensemble_model_churn.estimators) > 1`.

Another note: sklearn is very against doing any validation at model initiation, preferring to do such checking at fit time.  (This is because of the way they clone estimators in grid searches and such.)  So it's very unlikely that anything will be changed from your explicit input until you call `fit`.

Comment: That makes sense ```len(ensemble_model_churn.estimators)``` does give 30 (which is the answer I want). I was posting here because I did fit the model and I was getting the exact same result.

Comment: "exact same result" in what sense?  Accuracy, some other metric, predicted classes, predicted probabilities, ...?

Comment: I was using Area under ROC curve because my data was imbalanced. Based on that.